# Why is my List.Sort method in C# reversing the order of my list?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, icomparable

I have a list of items in a generic list:

- A1 (sort index 1)
- A2 (sort index 2)
- B1 (sort index 3)
- B2 (sort index 3)
- B3 (sort index 3)

The comparator on them takes the form:

```
this.sortIndex.CompareTo(other.sortIndex)
```

When I do a List.Sort() on the list of items, I get the following order out:

- A1
- A2
- B3
- B2
- B1

It has obviously worked in the sense that the sort indexes are in the right order,  but I really don't want it to be re-ordering the 'B' items.

Is there any tweak I can make to my comparator to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does List<T>.Sort method reorder equal IComparable<T> elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800007/why-does-listt-sort-method-reorder-equal-icomparablet-elements)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`OrderBy` preserves order for equal items:

```
myList = myList.OrderBy(item => item.SortIndex).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

you need to use a "[stable sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability)" algorithm if you don't want items that are equal to change position.

Check out "[merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)" for an example of a stable sort algorithm. Here's [an implementation](http://naudio.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/network/Show?projectName=naudio&changeSetId=46381#7784) of it in C#.

Answer (score 2):

`StableSort()` extension method for `List<T>` is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10449867/379279)

Answer (score 1):

You can change your comparator to do a secondary sort on the value:

```
if (this.sortIndex.CompareTo(other.sortIndex) == 0) // same sortIndex
{
   return this.Value.CompareTo(other.Value);
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Is that not doing exactly the same thing as the example I posted?

Comment: @Fiona: No, the code uses the value in a secondary comparison, but you have to do some corrections if you want to use it, as it messes up the primary comparison by returning zero instead of the result.

Comment: Ah I see. I don't have a secondary comparison to use really (although I could add an artifical one and this would work fine), the list order I want to preserve is based on the output of a pretty complex recursive function.

Answer (score 1):

Sort uses QuickSort, and it doesn't assure original sequence in case of comparison equality.

If you still want to use List.Sort you could add a second comparison with the original index like:

```
int c = this.sortIndex.CompareTo(other.sortIndex);
if (c == 0)
  c = this.originalIndex.CompareTo(other.originalIndex);
return c;
```

otherwise you can sort with other "stable" algorithms (e.g. LINQ OrderBy).